# Should animals not be fed on Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, fast-days, yonah-jonah-book-of

There is a line in The Book of Jonah that says:

> And he caused it to be proclaimed and published through Nineveh by the decree of the king and his nobles, saying: 'Let neither man nor beast, herd nor flock, taste any thing; let them not feed, nor drink water;

Does this mean that we, literally, should not feed animals (including Livestock and Pets, even Service Animals) on Yom Kippur or are animals not considered people (and are exempt from fasting) despite this line in the The Book?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29505/discussion-between-jason-d-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that we, literally, should not feed animals (including Livestock and Pets, even Service Animals) on Yom Kippur or are animals not considered people (and are exempt from fasting) despite this line in the The Book?

This line in Jonah is not discussing Yom Kippur. The entire book of Jonah is not discussing Yom Kippur. The fast discussed in Jonah was proclaimed by the ruler of Nineveh and followed whatever rules he decided on, and was on dates unknown to us (to the best of my knowledge).